# Network Error - React Native iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, https, axios, ios-simulator

I have a react native app that is throwing a `Network Error` when trying to communicate with the backend api.

**Troubleshooting I've tried:**

- The same payload works in [Postman](https://www.postman.com) (so the problem is the simulator/app, not the api)
- Using [Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) (via `await axios(config)`)
- Tried using both the localhost (http) and production (https) servers as the backend, same error
- Enabled all the App Transport Security Settings configs (Allow Arbitrary Loads, added Exception Domains)
- The content type is specified in the headers
- The simulator is connected to internet (I tried the browser)

Config:

```
 {"data": null, "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json", "X-JWT": "..."}, "method": "GET", "url": "https://example.com/..."}
```

Error:

```
{"message":"Network Error",
 "name":"Error",
 "stack":"createError@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:156907:26\nhandleError@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:156693:69\ndispatchEvent@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:30339:31\nsetReadyState@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:29485:33\n__didCompleteResponse@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:29291:29\nemit@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:2264:42\n__callFunction@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:3086:36\n@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:2810:31\n__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:3037:15\ncallFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.exampleapp:2809:21\ncallFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]",
 "config":{
    "transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,
    "headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json","X-JWT":"..."},
    "url":"https://example.com/...",
    "method":"get",
    "data":"null"
  },
 "status":null}
```

Technical Environment:

- React Native: 0.64.1
- Simulator: iOS 15.2 iPhone 13
- Device: macOS Monterey (12.0.1), Apple M1

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue using RN `0.64.2`

The issue seem to be related to Chrome debugger.

To fix the network error I just disable the debugger or use `react-native-debugger`:

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

If still not working try to set `data: undefined` for the `GET` request

Source for `data: undefined` fix and other possible fixes:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3192

**UPDATE: for newer RN versions I use Flipper**:
RN 0.66, Flipper App 0.99 and Flipper dependencies 0.99.
Flipper App 0.149+ works too but on Android network extension doesn't seem work very well sometimes.

I noticed using the Flipper version recommended in the react native
upgrade helper for my specific RN version worked best for both Android and iOS in my case.

Comment: The author has already stated that they've tried adjusting the App Transport Security settings, which you suggest in this answer (Info.plist)

Comment: The reference to the Github axios issue is what solved this for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**An awesome repo lets us know the APIs calls list with all headers and data being passed to API**.

Check out the [react-native-network-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-network-logger)

**We also can put see the exact error message as error.response.message in the catch of Axios call**.

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue with Axios call.

For Ex.

```
try {
    const addReminderRes = await axios({
        url: `authentication/addreminder`,
        data: formData,
        method: 'POST'
    })

    console.log('addReminderRes : ', addReminderRes)
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error : ", err.response.data)
}
```